# How to get unserialized data into a php array using jQuery .ajax()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
Array
(
    [infos] => address=&phone=&mail=
    [products] => Product0=C&Product1=B&Product2=A&Produic3=C
)
```

Above is what I managed to get in php using this javascript:

```
var $products = $("#selectProducts").find("input");
var serializedProducts = $products.serialize();

request = $.ajax({
    url: "backend.php",
    type: "post",
    data: {
        infos: serializedData,
        products: serializedProducts
    }
});
```

I have tried unserialize(), but it sends an error.
Also, `[Product0]`, `[Product1]`, etc are `<input>` names and `A`, `B`, `C` are `<input>` values.
**I do not know how much of these** `<input>` **will be sent to the php, it's up to the user.**

And here's what I would like to get in Php (or as close to this as possible) :

```
Array
(
    [infos] => address=&phone=&mail=
    [products] => Array (
                          [Product0] => C
                          [Product1] => B
                          [Product2] => A
                          [Product3] => C
                  )
)
```

I just can't figure how to create the corresponding javascript object.

Comment: If the two variables are serialized strings, why not join them together as a single data argument?  Seems like you're over complicating this

Comment: did you try `serializeArray()`?

Comment: @Taplar I can not mix those datas because they are not treated the same way by the php script. I absolutely need to separate them.

Comment: Well, according to https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php you can use that to parse the inner values once you get them in php

Comment: @AlwaysSunny Thanks. This is close enough to what I needed to solve the problem !
Explode() in php can also be helpful.